# How to delete by combining values with the same department_id?

Tags: sql, mysql

| department_id | protect | nature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Environmental | Police |
| 10 | Ararajuba | Protect |
| 10 | Jaguar | Protect |
| 10 | maned wolf | protect |
| 10 | animal | NGOs |
| 10 | sale of | animals |
| 0 | animal | abuse |
| 0 | sale of | animals |
| 1 | sale of | animals |
| 1 | animal | abuse |

I wish to delete all lines with the same `departament_id` that contain **protect sale of** and **animal protect along with nature abuse**, if **animal protect** contains **nature NGOs**, have to preserve **sale of animals** and **nature NGOs** with the same **departamento_id**.

Remembering that I do not know how to combine the same `departament_id` of the two **nature** different, I can not put in the function "**sale of**", how do I do?

```
DELETE FROM table 
WHERE (protect = 'sale of' 
       and protect = 'animal' 
       and nature = 'animals') 
      and department_id = department_id
```

The result must be this:

| department_id | protect | nature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Environmental | Police |
| 10 | Ararajuba | Protect |
| 10 | Jaguar | Protect |
| 10 | Maned Wolf | protect |
| 10 | animal | NGOs |
| 10 | sale of | animals |

Comment: Do you want to delete here then the lines ( leonardo, decaprio, 1 ) and ( brad, pitt, 1 ) but not delete ( brad, pitt, 0 )?

Comment: Changing the question, while it already has an answer, is never a good start.   Can you explain why the current answer (using different search criteria) is not the solution to your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the subquery to identify the department IDs that have records matching the given conditions. Then the outer DELETE statement then deletes all the rows from the table where the department_id matches the department_ids returned by the inner subquery.

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE department_id IN (
  SELECT department_id
  FROM table
  WHERE (surname = 'dicaprio' OR surname = 'pitt') AND name = 'brad'
  GROUP BY department_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT surname) = 2
)
```